# как сделать так, чтобы выводилось 21 а не 22

Tags: python, файлы

```
file = open('testest.txt','r',encoding = 'utf-8')
s = str(file.readline())


if s == 'g':
    print(21)
else:
    print(22)
```

в testest.txt             g
                          g

Comment: Записать в testest.txt  строку "g".

Comment: `readline` возвращает строку с символом переноса строки в конце. Значит нужно или дописать символ переноса строки в сравнении, или strip'нуть строку от пробельных символов, или записать файл так, чтобы он состоял из одной-единственной строки без каких-либо символов переноса

Answer (score -1):

Перед проверкой напишите

```
s.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: Неправильный ответ.